# Как создать или обновить структуру MongoDB с отношениями One to One с помощью prisma?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

В базе данных есть сущность User и ассоциированная с ним структура BasicInfo, которая содержит дополнительную информацию о пользователе. При первичной регистрации она не создается, однако когда пользователь заходит в настройки и сохраняет их, на сервер шлется json и этот json должен как-то поспособствовать созданию этой структуры.

База данных:

```
model User {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  verified  Boolean
  role      Role     @default(GUEST)
  basicInfo BasicInfo?
} 

model FullName {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  firstName       String?
  lastName        String?
  basicInfo       BasicInfo @relation(fields:[basicInfoId], references:[id]) 
  basicInfoId     String    @db.ObjectId @unique
}

model Career {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  company     String?
  role        String?
  basicInfo   BasicInfo @relation(fields:[basicInfoId], references:[id])
  basicInfoId String    @db.ObjectId @unique
}

model Education {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  university  String?
  faculty     String?
  basicInfo   BasicInfo @relation(fields:[basicInfoId], references:[id])
  basicInfoId String    @db.ObjectId @unique
}

model Location {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  country     String?
  region      String?
  timeZone    String?
  basicInfo   BasicInfo @relation(fields:[basicInfoId], references:[id])
  basicInfoId String    @db.ObjectId @unique
}

model BasicInfo {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user       User      @relation(fields:[userId], references:[id]) 
  userId     String    @db.ObjectId @unique
  fullName   FullName?
  career     Career?
  education  Education?
  location   Location?
}
```

Интерфейс json объекта, который приходит с сервера:

```
interface FullNameInput {
  firstName?: string
  lastName?: string
}

interface CareerInput {
  company?: string
  role?: string
}

interface EducationInput {
  university?: string
  faculty?: string
}

interface LocationInput {
  country?: string
  region?: string
  timeZone?: string
}

interface BasicInfoInput {
  fullName?: FullNameInput
  career?: CareerInput
  education?: EducationInput
  location?: LocationInput
}
```

Сервис который нужно реализовать:

```
  async upsetBasicInfo(params: {
    where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput
    data: BasicInfoInput
  }): Promise<BasicInfo> {
    const { where, data } = params
    return this.prisma.basicInfo.upsert({
      where: { userId: where.id },
      update: { ...data, user: { connect: { id: where.id } } },
      create: { ...data, user: { connect: { id: where.id } } },
    })
  }
}
```

'data' в таком виде ему не нравится, нужно каким-то образом превратить эту дату в удобоваримый тип призма. Я попробовал распарсить их превратить в BasicInfoCreateInput и в BasicInfoUpdateInput соответственно, но сам не справился :( запутался в иерархии вложенных 'create', 'where' и прочее.

По существу сервис должен либо создавать либо обновлять уже существующую структуру BasicInfo, увязанное с полем User.